Extracting text from pdfs with embedded fonts
I need to extract text from pdf files - seems simple enough.
Here is my problem.
When i open the pdf in a pdfviewer like Adobe Acrobat I see the text as normal text i can read it.
When i use iText7 for example to extract text i get texts like this one
R!"ina sa$!m!js even though it should be Rēķina saņēmējs
The problem is the embedded fonts where the character ! is the unicode char but when the font is applied it is rendered as ē.
Any ideas how to handle this. I tried to extract the fonts themselves from the pdf like this
using System;
using System.IO;
using iText.IO.Source;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

class PdfFontExtractor
{
private string pdfPath;
private string outputDir;

public PdfFontExtractor(string pdfPath, string outputDir)
{
    this.pdfPath = pdfPath;
    this.outputDir = outputDir;

    if (!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
    }
}

public void ExtractFonts()
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
    {
        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                ExtractFontsFromPage(page);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ExtractFontsFromPage(PdfPage page)
{
    PdfDictionary resources = page.GetResources().GetResource(PdfName.Font);

    foreach (PdfName fontName in resources.KeySet())
    {
        PdfDictionary fontDict = resources.GetAsDictionary(fontName);
        ExtractFont(fontDict);
    }
}

private void ExtractFont(PdfDictionary fontDict)
{
    PdfDictionary fontDescriptor = fontDict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.FontDescriptor);
    if (fontDescriptor != null)
    {
        PdfStream fontFileStream = null;

        if (fontDescriptor.ContainsKey(PdfName.FontFile))
            fontFileStream = fontDescriptor.GetAsStream(PdfName.FontFile);
        else if (fontDescriptor.ContainsKey(PdfName.FontFile2))
            fontFileStream = fontDescriptor.GetAsStream(PdfName.FontFile2);
        else if (fontDescriptor.ContainsKey(PdfName.FontFile3))
            fontFileStream = fontDescriptor.GetAsStream(PdfName.FontFile3);

        if (fontFileStream != null)
        {
            byte[] fontData = fontFileStream.GetBytes();

            if (fontData.Length > 1000)
            {
                string fontName = fontDict.GetAsName(PdfName.BaseFont).GetValue();
                fontName = fontName + ".ttf";

                string fontPath = Path.Combine(outputDir, fontName);
                File.WriteAllBytes(fontPath, fontData);
                Console.WriteLine($"Extracted font: {fontPath}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Skipped invalid font: {fontDict.GetAsName(PdfName.BaseFont).GetValue()}"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

}
It creates the files but they cannot be opened them.
I know it is possible to extract them using online tools like i2PDF
Maybe my code needs something.
My approach would be:

extract the fonts from the pdf
create images from the glyphs in the fonts
OCR the images and compare to the unicode chars the glyphs represent
change the text in the returned pdf text based on the gathered data

This is not a one off and the incoming pdf are with variations, so i want to automate this that i can give the program a pdf and it can return the correct text.
Solution is not manditory in c#. Python could be good as well.

Can you post a link to a sample PDF file for inspection?

There are multiple ways that you can solve this matter. I think the problem is with the library You are using. I can give you some libraries that can help you.

PyPDF2

import PyPDF2

with open('sample.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
    number_of_pages = reader.numPages
    page = reader.getPage(0)
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)


pdfplumber

import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open('sample.pdf') as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = first_page.extract_text()
    print(text)


PyMuPDF (fitz)

import fitz  # PyMuPDF

document = fitz.open('sample.pdf')
page = document.load_page(0)  # Page number starts from 0
text = page.get_text()
print(text)


pdfminer.six

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

text = extract_text('sample.pdf')
print(text)


Slate.

import slate

with open('sample.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    document = slate.PDF(file)
    print(document[0])  # First page text


PyPDF4:

import PyPDF4
with open('sample.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(file)
    number_of_pages = reader.numPages
    page = reader.getPage(0)
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)

Hope this solution will get your problem fixed...

Yeah i have tried PyPDF2, pdfplumber, PyMuPDF (fitz), pdfminer.six and Slate and they all extract the textual data. At first i thought it was some encoding at fault but when analyzing the pdf itself i noticed that font is applied on char level not word level and then inspecting in Adobe Acrobat Pro i figured out that the embedded fonts use special characters and represent them in completely different. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.
